# How to fix "HttpMessageNotReadableException: Required request body is missing"?

Tags: json, angular, spring-boot, content-type

I'm integrating Angular with Spring boot for basic CRUD application with login module.
Login module is working fine, whereas, for creation method I get: "HttpMessageNotReadableException: Required request body is missing" for that particular method.

This is for a basic login and CRUD operation app with angular 7 and spring boot.

```
  arrNewUser: any[] = [];
  url = 'http://localhost:8080/api/user-management/add';
  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private router: Router) { }

  private options = { headers: new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/json') };

  createUser(form: NgForm) {
    this.arrNewUser = form.value;
    console.log('array', this.arrNewUser);
    console.log('value', form.value);

    this.http.post(this.url, JSON.stringify(this.arrNewUser), this.options).subscribe((res: Response) => {
      console.log('Response:--', res.status);
      console.log(this.router.url);
    });

  }
```

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path="/api", method = {RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST})
@CrossOrigin(origins="http://localhost:4200")
public class ControllerClass {

    @PostMapping(path="/user-management/add", produces = { MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE })
    public Status addUsers(@RequestBody String data) {
            .......
            return status;
        }
```

I'm able to get required output thru postman and thru localhost:4200 angular port, but not from localhost:8080 i.e., spring boot address.

Comment: Try by removing `RequestMethod.GET` in the `@RequestMapping`

Comment: You set `@CrossOrigin(origins="http://localhost:4200")`, if you set it to `localhost:8080`, it will work for that. Then you might wonder why Postman works, postman doesn't need `CrossOrigin`

Comment: @ClementAmarnath I tried by removing `RequestMethod.GET`, it returns this-(type=Method Not Allowed, status=405).
Request method 'GET' not supported

Comment: If you have removed GET and then it is only POST is remaining is `method = { RequestMethod.POST}` to test this you have to use POSTMAN/RESTClient.

Comment: Is the URL specified in both Angular and Spring boot correct?